# My code works perfectly on 16F690 but not on 16F18313 using MPLAB X and XC8

Tags: pic, xc8

Okay, I have some code that works perfectly on a 16F690, but I need it to work on a 16F18313. The purpose of the code is to detect when a box lid is opened and closed, and turn on a fan for 25 seconds. Basically, the PIC starts in a sleep mode, wakes on interrupt, checks that the box lid was opened and closed, turns on a pin for 25 seconds, then clears the interrupts and goes back to sleep. I don't get any errors on either version.  When I run the code on the 16F18313, RA0 just stays high all the time.

I'm including all the C codes for both devices. First, here is the working code on the 16F690:

```
/*
 * File:   SH_Fan_16F690.c
 * Author: marka
 *
 * Created on October 4, 2023, 10:39 AM
 */

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Configuration bits
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO, WDTE = OFF, PWRTE = OFF, MCLRE = OFF, CP = OFF, CPD = OFF, BOREN = OFF, IESO = OFF, FCMEN = OFF

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000UL //4MHz
#define FAN_PIN  PORTCbits.RC1
#define SENSOR_PIN PORTAbits.RA3

static uint8_t previous_state = 1;
static uint8_t current_state = 1;
static uint16_t timer = 0;

void __interrupt() myISR(void);

void main(void) {
    // Setup
    // Configure RC1 as output for the fan and RA3 as input for the sensor
    TRISC1 = 0;
    TRISA3 = 1;

    // Initialize fan pin to low
    FAN_PIN = 0;

    // Enable GPIO Change Interrupt on RA3
    IOCA3 = 1;
    INTCONbits.RABIE = 1; // Enable Port A and B interrupt
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enable peripheral interrupt

    // Clear any stray interrupt flags
    INTCONbits.RABIF = 0;

    // Enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;

    // Main loop
    while (1) {
        // Put the device to sleep. It will wake up on GPIO change.
        asm("SLEEP");
    }
}

void __interrupt() myISR(void) {
    // Disable interrupts temporarily
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;

    // Check if the interrupt is due to a GPIO change
    if (INTCONbits.RABIF) {
        // Debouncing logic: wait 20 ms before re-reading the sensor state
        __delay_ms(20);

        // Read the current state of the sensor
        current_state = SENSOR_PIN;

        // Check state transition
        if ((previous_state == 0) && (current_state == 1)) {
            // Box was open, now closed
            // Turn on the fan for 25 seconds
            FAN_PIN = 1;

            // Wait 25 seconds
            for (timer = 1; timer <= 25000; ++timer) {
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

            // Turn off the fan
            FAN_PIN = 0;
        }

        // Update the previous state
        previous_state = current_state;

        // Clear the interrupt flag
        INTCONbits.RABIF = 0;
    }

    // Re-enable interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}
```

Here is the code on the 16F18313:

```
/*
 * File:   SH_Fan_16F18313.c
 * Author: marka
 *
 * Created on October 4, 2023, 10:39 AM
 */
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = ECH    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (EC (external clock) above 8 MHz)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with 2x PLL (32MHz))
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR; Weak pull-up enabled )
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT enabled, SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF       // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled, SBOREN bit ignored)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once; PPS registers remain locked after one clear/set cycle)
#pragma config STVREN = OFF      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000UL // 4MHz
#define FAN_PIN  LATAbits.LATA0  // Fan connected to RA0
#define SENSOR_PIN PORTAbits.RA2  // Sensor connected to RA2

static uint8_t previous_state = 1;
static uint8_t current_state = 1;
static uint16_t timer = 0;

void __interrupt() myISR(void);

void main(void) {
    // Setup
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0; // RA0 as output for the fan
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1; // RA2 as input for the sensor

    // Initialize fan pin to low
    FAN_PIN = 0;

    // Enable GPIO Change Interrupt on RA2
    IOCAPbits.IOCAP2 = 1;
    PIE0bits.IOCIE = 1; // Enable Interrupt-On-Change
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enable peripheral interrupt

    // Clear any stray interrupt flags
    PIR0bits.IOCIF = 0;

    // Enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;

    // Main loop
    while (1) {
        // Sleep mode
        asm("SLEEP");
    }
}

void __interrupt() myISR(void) {
    // Disable interrupts temporarily
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;

    // Check if the interrupt is due to a GPIO change
    if (PIR0bits.IOCIF) {
        // Debouncing: wait 20 ms before re-reading the sensor state
        __delay_ms(20);

        // Read the current state of the sensor
        current_state = SENSOR_PIN;

        // Check state transition
        if ((previous_state == 0) && (current_state == 1)) {
            // Box was open, now closed
            FAN_PIN = 1; // Turn on the fan for 25 seconds

            // Wait 25 seconds
            for (timer = 1; timer <= 25000; ++timer) {
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

            // Turn off the fan
            FAN_PIN = 0;
        }

        // Update the previous state
        previous_state = current_state;

        // Clear the interrupt flag
        PIR0bits.IOCIF = 0;
    }

    // Re-enable interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to enable digital I/O for PORTA.

And the way your code clears the Interrupt-On-Change may not work.

This code may be better:

```
/*
 * File:   SH_Fan_16F18313.c
 * Author: marka
 *
 * Created on October 4, 2023, 10:39 AM
 * 
 *                    PIC16F18313
 *              +---------:_:---------:
 *     5v0 -> 1 : VDD             VSS : 8 <- GND
 *         <> 2 : RA5/AN5     AN0/RA0 : 7 <> PGD
 *         <> 3 : RA4/AN4     AN1/RA1 : 6 <> PGC
 *     VPP -> 4 : RA3/MCLRn   AN2/RA2 : 5 <>
 *              +---------------------+
 *                       DIP-8
 */
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = ECH    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (EC (external clock) above 8 MHz)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with 2x PLL (32MHz))
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR; Weak pull-up enabled )
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT enabled, SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF       // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled, SBOREN bit ignored)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once; PPS registers remain locked after one clear/set cycle)
#pragma config STVREN = OFF      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000UL // 4MHz
#define FAN_PIN  LATAbits.LATA0  // Fan connected to RA0
#define SENSOR_PIN PORTAbits.RA2  // Sensor connected to RA2

static uint8_t previous_state = 1;
static uint8_t current_state = 1;
static uint16_t timer = 0;

void __interrupt() myISR(void);

void main(void) {
    
    /*
     * Add code to setup GPIO hardware
     */
    ANSELA = 0;     /* make all GPIO pins digital I/O DS40001799F-page 13 */
    SLRCONA = 0;    /* set output slew rate to maximum */
    ODCONA = 0;     /* set output as push-pull */
    WPUA = 0;       /* turn off weak pull-ups */
    
    // Setup
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0; // RA0 as output for the fan
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1; // RA2 as input for the sensor

    // Initialize fan pin to low
    FAN_PIN = 0;

    // Enable GPIO Change Interrupt on RA2
    IOCAPbits.IOCAP2 = 1;
    PIE0bits.IOCIE = 1; // Enable Interrupt-On-Change
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enable peripheral interrupt

    // Clear any stray interrupt flags
    PORTA;                  /* Read PORTA to clear any mismatch for IOC */
    IOCAF &= (~IOCAF);      /* Clear IOC bits that changed */
    PIR0bits.IOCIF = 0;

    // Enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;

    // Main loop
    while (1) {
        // Sleep mode
        asm("SLEEP");
    }
}

void __interrupt() myISR(void) {
    // Check if the interrupt is due to a GPIO change
    if (PIR0bits.IOCIF) {
        // Debouncing: wait 20 ms before re-reading the sensor state
        __delay_ms(20);

        // Read the current state of the sensor
        current_state = SENSOR_PIN;

        // Check state transition
        if ((previous_state == 0) && (current_state == 1)) {
            // Box was open, now closed
            FAN_PIN = 1; // Turn on the fan for 25 seconds

            // Wait 25 seconds
            for (timer = 1; timer <= 25000; ++timer) {
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

            // Turn off the fan
            FAN_PIN = 0;
        }

        // Update the previous state
        previous_state = current_state;

        // Clear the interrupt flag
        PORTA;                  /* Read PORTA to clear any mismatch for IOC */
        IOCAF &= (~IOCAF);      /* Clear IOC bits that changed */
        PIR0bits.IOCIF = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dan1138  for your response. I could not get any signs of life from the PIC 16F18313, which leads me to believe it's a configuration issue. I replaced the sleep mode with a LED blink and still get nothing. So I rewrote the code for a 12F675 because I have a bunch on-hand and I'm much more familiar with them. The code "works", but it is very intermittent. In my test circuit, it turns on the fan about every 3rd or 4th cycle of opening and closing the switch for the lid. Any suggestions on making it more reliable at detecting the switch opening and closing? I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @mokeymark, Create a git hub repository to show your complete project. All the code and circuit diagrams of what you are trying along with photos of the hardware you have assembled. My guess is that your issues are somewhere other than just in the firmware.

Comment: I will do that and I'll let you know when it's up. Thank you.

Comment: I got the code working! This for a tiny 50mm x 50mm box with a miniature fan inside. Because of the size, I wanted to run it off of coin cells. When testing on the bench, I realized that the CR2032's have a high internal resistance and can't reliably supply the current for the fan. I'm having better luck with SR44 silver oxide batteries. I am open to any suggestions to make this better or more efficient. I may need to use PWM for the fan. Here is the git hub: https://github.com/mokeylaser/Tiny-Box-Fan